# Is it possible to detect object using CoreML model and find measurement of that object?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

I want to detect object categories like door, window using CoreML and ARKit and I want to find measurements (like height, width and area) of a door.

How can I detect objects and add some overlay shape on that object so I could find real world position and measurement of that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use ARKit's built-in object detection algorithm for that task**. It's simple and power.

With ARKit's [object detection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) you can detect your door (preliminary scanned or shot on smartphone).

The following code helps you detect real world objects (like door) and place 3D object or 3D text at `ARObjectAnchor` position:

```
import ARKit

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                 didAdd node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        if let _ = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {

            let text = SCNText(string: "SIZE OF THIS OBJECT IS...",
                       extrusionDepth: 0.05)

            text.flatness = 0.5
            text.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)

            let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
            textNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
            textNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01) 

            node.addChildNode(textNode)
        }
    }
}
```

And supply an Xcode's folder `Resources` with images of your real-life objects.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.debugOptions = .showFeaturePoints
        sceneView.delegate = self

        guard let dObj = ARReferenceObject.referenceObjects(inGroupNamed: "Resources", 
                                                                  bundle: nil) 
        else {
            fatalError("There's no reference image")
            return
        }

        configuration.detectionObjects = dObj
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
}
```